# No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

I had installed "pytesseract" and "tesseract", but I keep getting the error:

```
    "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'"

……$ pip install pytesseract
Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pytesseract)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Pillow->pytesseract)

……$ pip install tesseract
Requirement already satisfied: tesseract in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: Tag your operating system.

Comment: I beleive so you have installed tesseract-ocr  and added it to your environment path if it is for windows ?  And your problem is on pytesseract or tesseract ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using anaconda prompt for running your application, you have to specify the location of your tesseract executable inside your code, before you call tesseract.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<path_to_tesseract>'
```

Example:

I am using windows, so it looks like

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR'
```

Another way to make it work in windows is to **add location of tesseract to the path environment variable** and execute the program from the cmd prompt